# Actual Use Of "" in HandleBars

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, frontend, handlebars.js

I am struck in this problem for quite a while:

While using dynamic-dropdown in hbs file, I am unable to figure out why my api call isn't happening when not placed under "".

Example:

**API Call happens for:**

```
{{else if (@model.columnName === "status")}}
      {{web-comp/dynamic-dropdown
          type="status"
          disabled=@disabled
          options=@dropdownoptions
          selected=(find-by "value" @model.value @dropdownoptions)
          fieldType="value"
          searchApi="/google/xyz.json?&data_type&q="
          searchPlaceHolder="Searching"
       }}
```

**But for some reason the API call doesn't happen for this:**

```
{{else if (@model.columnName === status)}}
      {{web-comp/dynamic-dropdown
          type="status"
          disabled=@disabled
          options=@dropdownoptions
          selected=(find-by "value" @model.value @dropdownoptions)
          fieldType="value"
          searchApi="/google/xyz.json?&data_type&q="
          searchPlaceHolder="Searching"
       }}
```

The only difference is "" in the word "status"

Another problem which I am facing is the dropdownoptions are not getting selected in the UI after adding **"status"** in else if condition. Any idea for why it is happening ? When added without "" then it is working fine but the API call isn't getting triggered.

The final solution which i am looking for is the dropdown to behave normally and get the API call when added a query in search bar.

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks !

Comment: `status` (without quotes) is a variable, right? Is it set to the string "status"? Otherwise, it's obvious why this is not working.

Comment: In the payload it is coming as "status" (with quotes), but adding the quotes is not letting me select the dropdownoptions

Answer (score 1):

`"status"` compares to the **string** `"status"`.
`status` compares to the **variable** `status`.